# how to extract the list of values from a specific drop down box in a web form, using java/jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, html-content-extraction

I want to extract all the values for a specific drop down list box in a web form.

In the source code of this web form, the relevant code for this particular drop down, is given below--

```
<div align="left"><select name="CATEGORY_ID">
<option label="[Top]" value="0" selected="selected">[Top]</option>
<option label="|___Arts &amp; Humanities" value="1">|___Arts &amp; Humanities</option>
<option label="|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|___Art History" value="2">|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|___Art History</option>
----many more values----
<option label="|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|___Work" value="453">|&nbsp;&nbsp;nbsp;|___Work</option>

</select>
</div>
```

I want to extract both the actual values  (ie option ... value="" ) as well as the value shown on screen (ie option label="" )...Can this be done in JSP/Java? And ideally done using only classes supported by Google App Engine? (Even if you can suggest a way to do this but are not sure if that way is supported by Google App Engine for Java, even then kindly suggest your method...)

Comment: I do not understand _why_ you want to extract the label. It's value should identify the label in your backend. If you transfer the label as well you can't be sure the user did not modify it on the fly...

Comment: I am trying to create an application that automates submission of data to remote web forms...for this purpose i am already collecting data about such forms including names of various fields and max/min size per field... For multiple choice fields I plan to dynamically retrieve all values as per the site(immediately before I open the form to submit data to that site)...The site is not mine, it is a 3rd party site... thats why I am thinking of obtaining the label as well as value..Different sites may have different label/value combinations...Hence the need to extract both...

Comment: Thanks, was just interested. I don't know if GAE does support this, I only know of JavaScript for doing things like that, e.g. dynamically add the required fields to a form before submission...

Comment: So.. You're basically asking how to download the HTML output of website XYZ and then parse all `<option>` elements so that you have labels/values in a `Map<K, V>` which you in turn finally redisplay as options of a `<select>` of your own JSP?

Comment: yes, that is what i require...(not for all values though- i know before hand which all fields represent multiple choice values- i want the values for such fields only)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is to use a HTML parser for this. I don't think that GAE ships with any one. But you should be able to drop one in your `/WEB-INF/lib`. I'd suggest to grab [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for this job. You should then able to obtain all options of a `<select name="CATEGORY_ID">` of the external website as follows in a servlet:

```java
Map<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://other.com/some.html").get();

for (Element option : document.select("select[name=CATEGORY_ID] options")) {
    options.put(option.attr("value"), option.text());
}

request.setAttribute("options", options);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And then in JSP redisplay it as follows:

```xml
<select name="category">
    <c:forEach items="${options}" var="option">
        <option value="${option.key}"><c:out value="${option.value}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

The `label` attribute is by the way unnecessary as it's a silly MSIE-proprietary attribute. It's the body of the `<option>` element which is to be shown as visible label.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that by parsing the form, in its simplest form you can do that with java.lang.String methods, get the substring between "select" tags, then get the substrings between "option" tags and then parse each string to find values for "label=" and "value=". I guess you can try some parsing libraries for html too.